# Windows equivalent of linux cksum command

Tags: windows, checksum

I'm looking for a way to compute CRC checksums cross platform.

`cksum` works on Linux, AIX, HP-UX Itanium, Solaris, but is there an equivalent command available in Windows too?

```
%cksum run.sh
1491301976 652 run.sh
```

Note: I'm not interested in third party tools.

Comment: On Windows, you can install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [GNU CoreUtils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) to get `cksum`.

Comment: Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) works: `wsl cksum run.sh`

Answer (score 152, accepted):

In Windows (command prompt) you can use CertUtil, here is the syntax:

```
CertUtil [Options] -hashfile InFile [HashAlgorithm]
```

for syntax explanation type in cmd:

```
CertUtil -hashfile -?
```

example:

```
CertUtil -hashfile C:\myFile.txt MD5
```

default is SHA1 it supports: MD2, MD4, MD5, SHA1, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512. Unfortunately no CRC32 as Unix shell does.

Here is a link if you want to find out more:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc732443(v=ws.11)

Comment: It will be a customer system and they might not have a third party tool installed, so I need to go with something which comes within windows. At present I am using java to get this done. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: CertUtil comes within windows

Comment: side note: cksum in unix, uses CRC32 compliant with POSIX 1003.2

Comment: This is the best built-in answer though the output is incredibly annoying as it has other non-checksum lines printed to stdout before and after the checksum as well (on Windows 10, at least).

Answer (score 9):

It looks as if there is an unsupported tool for checksums from MS. It's light on features but appears to do what you're asking for. It was published in August of 2012. It's called "Microsoft File Checksum Integrity Verifier".

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533

Comment: N.B. does not support CRC checks, just MD5 and SHA-1.

Comment: IBM has a [list of MD5 checksum apps](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21496703) for different platforms

Comment: There is a kind of manual with examples of command line to use the utility at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/File_Checksum_Integrity_Verifier_(FCIV)_Examples#Making_Hashes

Answer (score 5):

To avoid annoying non-checksum lines:

```
 CertUtil -v -hashfile "your_file" SHA1 | FIND /V "CertUtil"
```

This will display only line(s) *NOT* containing `CertUtil`

Comment: `-v` is counter-productive here.

Comment: Oddly, the `find` command works differently in PowerShell than it does in the Command Prompt. Try `findstr` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Open Windows PowerShell, and use the below command:

```
Get-FileHash C:\Users\Deepak\Downloads\ubuntu-20.10-desktop-amd64.iso
```

Answer (score 2):

In the year 2019, Microsoft offers the [following solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash?view=powershell-6) for Windows 10. This solution works for SHA256 checksum.

Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key. Type `PowerShell`. Select *Windows Powershell*. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. Paste the command

```
Get-FileHash C:\Users\Donald\Downloads\File-to-be-checked-by-sha256.exe | Format-List
```

Replace `File-to-be-checked-by-sha256.exe` by the name of your file to be checked.

Replace the path to your path where the file is.
Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
Powershell then shows the following

```
Algorithm : SHA256
Hash      : 123456789ABCDEFGH1234567890...
Path      :  C:\Users\Donald\Downloads\File-to-be-checked-by-sha256.exe
```

Comment: It also doesn't offer actual CRC32.

Comment: Or just pick out the hash value with a PowerShell command like this: `(Get-FileHash C:\your\file\here).Hash`

Answer (score 2):

Algorithm the cksum command in linux
https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=cksum&category=1&russian=5

Powershell implementation:

```powershell
function UNSIGNED($u) {
    return $u -band 0xffffffff
}

function memcrc32($b){

     $crctab = [uint32]"0x00000000", [uint32]"0x04c11db7", [uint32]"0x09823b6e", [uint32]"0x0d4326d9", [uint32]"0x130476dc",
        [uint32]"0x17c56b6b", [uint32]"0x1a864db2", [uint32]"0x1e475005", [uint32]"0x2608edb8", [uint32]"0x22c9f00f",
        [uint32]"0x2f8ad6d6", [uint32]"0x2b4bcb61", [uint32]"0x350c9b64", [uint32]"0x31cd86d3", [uint32]"0x3c8ea00a",
        [uint32]"0x384fbdbd", [uint32]"0x4c11db70", [uint32]"0x48d0c6c7", [uint32]"0x4593e01e", [uint32]"0x4152fda9",
        [uint32]"0x5f15adac", [uint32]"0x5bd4b01b", [uint32]"0x569796c2", [uint32]"0x52568b75", [uint32]"0x6a1936c8",
        [uint32]"0x6ed82b7f", [uint32]"0x639b0da6", [uint32]"0x675a1011", [uint32]"0x791d4014", [uint32]"0x7ddc5da3",
        [uint32]"0x709f7b7a", [uint32]"0x745e66cd", [uint32]"0x9823b6e0", [uint32]"0x9ce2ab57", [uint32]"0x91a18d8e",
        [uint32]"0x95609039", [uint32]"0x8b27c03c", [uint32]"0x8fe6dd8b", [uint32]"0x82a5fb52", [uint32]"0x8664e6e5",
        [uint32]"0xbe2b5b58", [uint32]"0xbaea46ef", [uint32]"0xb7a96036", [uint32]"0xb3687d81", [uint32]"0xad2f2d84",
        [uint32]"0xa9ee3033", [uint32]"0xa4ad16ea", [uint32]"0xa06c0b5d", [uint32]"0xd4326d90", [uint32]"0xd0f37027",
        [uint32]"0xddb056fe", [uint32]"0xd9714b49", [uint32]"0xc7361b4c", [uint32]"0xc3f706fb", [uint32]"0xceb42022",
        [uint32]"0xca753d95", [uint32]"0xf23a8028", [uint32]"0xf6fb9d9f", [uint32]"0xfbb8bb46", [uint32]"0xff79a6f1",
        [uint32]"0xe13ef6f4", [uint32]"0xe5ffeb43", [uint32]"0xe8bccd9a", [uint32]"0xec7dd02d", [uint32]"0x34867077",
        [uint32]"0x30476dc0", [uint32]"0x3d044b19", [uint32]"0x39c556ae", [uint32]"0x278206ab", [uint32]"0x23431b1c",
        [uint32]"0x2e003dc5", [uint32]"0x2ac12072", [uint32]"0x128e9dcf", [uint32]"0x164f8078", [uint32]"0x1b0ca6a1",
        [uint32]"0x1fcdbb16", [uint32]"0x018aeb13", [uint32]"0x054bf6a4", [uint32]"0x0808d07d", [uint32]"0x0cc9cdca",
        [uint32]"0x7897ab07", [uint32]"0x7c56b6b0", [uint32]"0x71159069", [uint32]"0x75d48dde", [uint32]"0x6b93dddb",
        [uint32]"0x6f52c06c", [uint32]"0x6211e6b5", [uint32]"0x66d0fb02", [uint32]"0x5e9f46bf", [uint32]"0x5a5e5b08",
        [uint32]"0x571d7dd1", [uint32]"0x53dc6066", [uint32]"0x4d9b3063", [uint32]"0x495a2dd4", [uint32]"0x44190b0d",
        [uint32]"0x40d816ba", [uint32]"0xaca5c697", [uint32]"0xa864db20", [uint32]"0xa527fdf9", [uint32]"0xa1e6e04e",
        [uint32]"0xbfa1b04b", [uint32]"0xbb60adfc", [uint32]"0xb6238b25", [uint32]"0xb2e29692", [uint32]"0x8aad2b2f",
        [uint32]"0x8e6c3698", [uint32]"0x832f1041", [uint32]"0x87ee0df6", [uint32]"0x99a95df3", [uint32]"0x9d684044",
        [uint32]"0x902b669d", [uint32]"0x94ea7b2a", [uint32]"0xe0b41de7", [uint32]"0xe4750050", [uint32]"0xe9362689",
        [uint32]"0xedf73b3e", [uint32]"0xf3b06b3b", [uint32]"0xf771768c", [uint32]"0xfa325055", [uint32]"0xfef34de2",
        [uint32]"0xc6bcf05f", [uint32]"0xc27dede8", [uint32]"0xcf3ecb31", [uint32]"0xcbffd686", [uint32]"0xd5b88683",
        [uint32]"0xd1799b34", [uint32]"0xdc3abded", [uint32]"0xd8fba05a", [uint32]"0x690ce0ee", [uint32]"0x6dcdfd59",
        [uint32]"0x608edb80", [uint32]"0x644fc637", [uint32]"0x7a089632", [uint32]"0x7ec98b85", [uint32]"0x738aad5c",
        [uint32]"0x774bb0eb", [uint32]"0x4f040d56", [uint32]"0x4bc510e1", [uint32]"0x46863638", [uint32]"0x42472b8f",
        [uint32]"0x5c007b8a", [uint32]"0x58c1663d", [uint32]"0x558240e4", [uint32]"0x51435d53", [uint32]"0x251d3b9e",
        [uint32]"0x21dc2629", [uint32]"0x2c9f00f0", [uint32]"0x285e1d47", [uint32]"0x36194d42", [uint32]"0x32d850f5",
        [uint32]"0x3f9b762c", [uint32]"0x3b5a6b9b", [uint32]"0x0315d626", [uint32]"0x07d4cb91", [uint32]"0x0a97ed48",
        [uint32]"0x0e56f0ff", [uint32]"0x1011a0fa", [uint32]"0x14d0bd4d", [uint32]"0x19939b94", [uint32]"0x1d528623",
        [uint32]"0xf12f560e", [uint32]"0xf5ee4bb9", [uint32]"0xf8ad6d60", [uint32]"0xfc6c70d7", [uint32]"0xe22b20d2",
        [uint32]"0xe6ea3d65", [uint32]"0xeba91bbc", [uint32]"0xef68060b", [uint32]"0xd727bbb6", [uint32]"0xd3e6a601",
        [uint32]"0xdea580d8", [uint32]"0xda649d6f", [uint32]"0xc423cd6a", [uint32]"0xc0e2d0dd", [uint32]"0xcda1f604",
        [uint32]"0xc960ebb3", [uint32]"0xbd3e8d7e", [uint32]"0xb9ff90c9", [uint32]"0xb4bcb610", [uint32]"0xb07daba7",
        [uint32]"0xae3afba2", [uint32]"0xaafbe615", [uint32]"0xa7b8c0cc", [uint32]"0xa379dd7b", [uint32]"0x9b3660c6",
        [uint32]"0x9ff77d71", [uint32]"0x92b45ba8", [uint32]"0x9675461f", [uint32]"0x8832161a", [uint32]"0x8cf30bad",
        [uint32]"0x81b02d74", [uint32]"0x857130c3", [uint32]"0x5d8a9099", [uint32]"0x594b8d2e", [uint32]"0x5408abf7",
        [uint32]"0x50c9b640", [uint32]"0x4e8ee645", [uint32]"0x4a4ffbf2", [uint32]"0x470cdd2b", [uint32]"0x43cdc09c",
        [uint32]"0x7b827d21", [uint32]"0x7f436096", [uint32]"0x7200464f", [uint32]"0x76c15bf8", [uint32]"0x68860bfd",
        [uint32]"0x6c47164a", [uint32]"0x61043093", [uint32]"0x65c52d24", [uint32]"0x119b4be9", [uint32]"0x155a565e",
        [uint32]"0x18197087", [uint32]"0x1cd86d30", [uint32]"0x029f3d35", [uint32]"0x065e2082", [uint32]"0x0b1d065b",
        [uint32]"0x0fdc1bec", [uint32]"0x3793a651", [uint32]"0x3352bbe6", [uint32]"0x3e119d3f", [uint32]"0x3ad08088",
        [uint32]"0x2497d08d", [uint32]"0x2056cd3a", [uint32]"0x2d15ebe3", [uint32]"0x29d4f654", [uint32]"0xc5a92679",
        [uint32]"0xc1683bce", [uint32]"0xcc2b1d17", [uint32]"0xc8ea00a0", [uint32]"0xd6ad50a5", [uint32]"0xd26c4d12",
        [uint32]"0xdf2f6bcb", [uint32]"0xdbee767c", [uint32]"0xe3a1cbc1", [uint32]"0xe760d676", [uint32]"0xea23f0af",
        [uint32]"0xeee2ed18", [uint32]"0xf0a5bd1d", [uint32]"0xf464a0aa", [uint32]"0xf9278673", [uint32]"0xfde69bc4",
        [uint32]"0x89b8fd09", [uint32]"0x8d79e0be", [uint32]"0x803ac667", [uint32]"0x84fbdbd0", [uint32]"0x9abc8bd5",
        [uint32]"0x9e7d9662", [uint32]"0x933eb0bb", [uint32]"0x97ffad0c", [uint32]"0xafb010b1", [uint32]"0xab710d06",
        [uint32]"0xa6322bdf", [uint32]"0xa2f33668", [uint32]"0xbcb4666d", [uint32]"0xb8757bda", [uint32]"0xb5365d03",
        [uint32]"0xb1f740b4"

    $n = $b.length
    $i = $c = $s = 0

    foreach ($c in $b){
      $tabidx = (($s -shr 24) -bxor $c)
      $s = ((UNSIGNED($s -shl 8)) -bxor $crctab[$tabidx])
    }

   while($n -ne 0){
        $c = ($n -band 0xff)
        $n = ($n -shr 8)
        $s = (($s -shl 8) -bxor ($crctab[($s -shr 24) -bxor $c]))
   }
   return (-bnot $s)
}


function cksum($fname) {
     
      $buffer=[System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($fname)
      $CRC = memcrc32($buffer)
      
      Write-Host $CRC $buffer.length "$fname"
    }


cksum("PATH_TO_FILE")
```

---

More fustly implementation, with C# code.
Works with powershell2.0

```powershell
$Source = @"
using System;
public class memcrc
{
    public uint check(byte[] b)
    {
        uint[] crctab = {
            0x00000000,
            0x04c11db7, 0x09823b6e, 0x0d4326d9, 0x130476dc, 0x17c56b6b,
            0x1a864db2, 0x1e475005, 0x2608edb8, 0x22c9f00f, 0x2f8ad6d6,
            0x2b4bcb61, 0x350c9b64, 0x31cd86d3, 0x3c8ea00a, 0x384fbdbd,
            0x4c11db70, 0x48d0c6c7, 0x4593e01e, 0x4152fda9, 0x5f15adac,
            0x5bd4b01b, 0x569796c2, 0x52568b75, 0x6a1936c8, 0x6ed82b7f,
            0x639b0da6, 0x675a1011, 0x791d4014, 0x7ddc5da3, 0x709f7b7a,
            0x745e66cd, 0x9823b6e0, 0x9ce2ab57, 0x91a18d8e, 0x95609039,
            0x8b27c03c, 0x8fe6dd8b, 0x82a5fb52, 0x8664e6e5, 0xbe2b5b58,
            0xbaea46ef, 0xb7a96036, 0xb3687d81, 0xad2f2d84, 0xa9ee3033,
            0xa4ad16ea, 0xa06c0b5d, 0xd4326d90, 0xd0f37027, 0xddb056fe,
            0xd9714b49, 0xc7361b4c, 0xc3f706fb, 0xceb42022, 0xca753d95,
            0xf23a8028, 0xf6fb9d9f, 0xfbb8bb46, 0xff79a6f1, 0xe13ef6f4,
            0xe5ffeb43, 0xe8bccd9a, 0xec7dd02d, 0x34867077, 0x30476dc0,
            0x3d044b19, 0x39c556ae, 0x278206ab, 0x23431b1c, 0x2e003dc5,
            0x2ac12072, 0x128e9dcf, 0x164f8078, 0x1b0ca6a1, 0x1fcdbb16,
            0x018aeb13, 0x054bf6a4, 0x0808d07d, 0x0cc9cdca, 0x7897ab07,
            0x7c56b6b0, 0x71159069, 0x75d48dde, 0x6b93dddb, 0x6f52c06c,
            0x6211e6b5, 0x66d0fb02, 0x5e9f46bf, 0x5a5e5b08, 0x571d7dd1,
            0x53dc6066, 0x4d9b3063, 0x495a2dd4, 0x44190b0d, 0x40d816ba,
            0xaca5c697, 0xa864db20, 0xa527fdf9, 0xa1e6e04e, 0xbfa1b04b,
            0xbb60adfc, 0xb6238b25, 0xb2e29692, 0x8aad2b2f, 0x8e6c3698,
            0x832f1041, 0x87ee0df6, 0x99a95df3, 0x9d684044, 0x902b669d,
            0x94ea7b2a, 0xe0b41de7, 0xe4750050, 0xe9362689, 0xedf73b3e,
            0xf3b06b3b, 0xf771768c, 0xfa325055, 0xfef34de2, 0xc6bcf05f,
            0xc27dede8, 0xcf3ecb31, 0xcbffd686, 0xd5b88683, 0xd1799b34,
            0xdc3abded, 0xd8fba05a, 0x690ce0ee, 0x6dcdfd59, 0x608edb80,
            0x644fc637, 0x7a089632, 0x7ec98b85, 0x738aad5c, 0x774bb0eb,
            0x4f040d56, 0x4bc510e1, 0x46863638, 0x42472b8f, 0x5c007b8a,
            0x58c1663d, 0x558240e4, 0x51435d53, 0x251d3b9e, 0x21dc2629,
            0x2c9f00f0, 0x285e1d47, 0x36194d42, 0x32d850f5, 0x3f9b762c,
            0x3b5a6b9b, 0x0315d626, 0x07d4cb91, 0x0a97ed48, 0x0e56f0ff,
            0x1011a0fa, 0x14d0bd4d, 0x19939b94, 0x1d528623, 0xf12f560e,
            0xf5ee4bb9, 0xf8ad6d60, 0xfc6c70d7, 0xe22b20d2, 0xe6ea3d65,
            0xeba91bbc, 0xef68060b, 0xd727bbb6, 0xd3e6a601, 0xdea580d8,
            0xda649d6f, 0xc423cd6a, 0xc0e2d0dd, 0xcda1f604, 0xc960ebb3,
            0xbd3e8d7e, 0xb9ff90c9, 0xb4bcb610, 0xb07daba7, 0xae3afba2,
            0xaafbe615, 0xa7b8c0cc, 0xa379dd7b, 0x9b3660c6, 0x9ff77d71,
            0x92b45ba8, 0x9675461f, 0x8832161a, 0x8cf30bad, 0x81b02d74,
            0x857130c3, 0x5d8a9099, 0x594b8d2e, 0x5408abf7, 0x50c9b640,
            0x4e8ee645, 0x4a4ffbf2, 0x470cdd2b, 0x43cdc09c, 0x7b827d21,
            0x7f436096, 0x7200464f, 0x76c15bf8, 0x68860bfd, 0x6c47164a,
            0x61043093, 0x65c52d24, 0x119b4be9, 0x155a565e, 0x18197087,
            0x1cd86d30, 0x029f3d35, 0x065e2082, 0x0b1d065b, 0x0fdc1bec,
            0x3793a651, 0x3352bbe6, 0x3e119d3f, 0x3ad08088, 0x2497d08d,
            0x2056cd3a, 0x2d15ebe3, 0x29d4f654, 0xc5a92679, 0xc1683bce,
            0xcc2b1d17, 0xc8ea00a0, 0xd6ad50a5, 0xd26c4d12, 0xdf2f6bcb,
            0xdbee767c, 0xe3a1cbc1, 0xe760d676, 0xea23f0af, 0xeee2ed18,
            0xf0a5bd1d, 0xf464a0aa, 0xf9278673, 0xfde69bc4, 0x89b8fd09,
            0x8d79e0be, 0x803ac667, 0x84fbdbd0, 0x9abc8bd5, 0x9e7d9662,
            0x933eb0bb, 0x97ffad0c, 0xafb010b1, 0xab710d06, 0xa6322bdf,
            0xa2f33668, 0xbcb4666d, 0xb8757bda, 0xb5365d03, 0xb1f740b4
            };

        uint i=0, tabidx=0;
        uint c = 0, s = 0;
        uint n = (uint) b.Length;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            c = b[i];
            tabidx = (s >> 24) ^ c;
            s = (s << 8) ^ crctab[tabidx];
        }

        while (n != 0) {
            c = n & 0xff;
            n >>= 8;
            s = (s << 8) ^ crctab[(s >> 24) ^ c];
        }
        return ~s;
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source
$memcrc32 = New-Object memcrc

function cksum($fname) {
      $buffer=[System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($fname)
      $CRC = $memcrc32.check($buffer)
      return $CRC
    }

cksum C:\File.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a C# implementation of the *nix cksum command line utility for windows https://cksum.codeplex.com/

Comment: Please don't just post a link to the answer, try to explain it yourself.

Comment: @tux3          There is a short explanation that describes the purpose of the link, and the answer is relevant to the question . But since I'm new here and that was my first post in stackoverflow, I may have missed something. So I would be grateful if you describe more clearly to me that what else should be explained, so that I can improve my answers in the future and be more helpful to the community

Comment: "Try to explain it yourself" in a post linking to an *application*.  People don't always use common sense...

Answer (score 1):

In combination of answers of @Cassian and @Hllitec and from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42706309/1001717 here my solution, where I put (only!) the checksum value into a variable for further processing:

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('certutil -v -hashfile myPackage.nupkg SHA256 ^| find /i /v "sha256" ^| find /i /v "certutil"') do set myVar=%i
```

To test the output you can add a piped echo command with the var:

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('certutil -v -hashfile myPackage.nupkg SHA256 ^| find /i /v "sha256" ^| find /i /v "certutil"') do set myVar=%i | echo %myVar%
```

A bit off-topic, but FYI: I used this before uploading my NuGet package to Artifactory. BTW. as alternative you can use JFrog CLI, where checksum is calculated automatically.