# Saving result of CertUtil -hashfile to a variable and remove spaces of the hash

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, certutil

I want to save a result of

```
CertUtil -hashfile "path_to_file" MD5
```

to a variable and remove spaces of the hash in command line command (to be more particular, I wan to use this in Command Line of post-processing in VS 2015 C++).

Currently the result is as follows:

> 1) C:\Users\admin>CertUtil -hashfile ping.txt MD5
> 2) MD5 hash of file ping.txt:
> 3) 4f 75 c2 2c 20 b4 81 54 72 2c a5 7c 95 7a 66 88 
> 4) CertUtil:
>   -hashfile command completed successfully.

I just need the line `3)` - save the hexa string to a variable and then remove the spaces.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite the answer above, typicall **setlocal enabledelayedexpansion** issue

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count=1 
for /f "skip=1 delims=:" %%a in ('CertUtil -hashfile "ping.txt" MD5') do (
  if !count! equ 1 set "md5=%%a"
  set/a count+=1
)
set "md5=%md5: =%
echo %md5%
endlocal
exit/B
```

Comment: my script has no problems with delayed expansion.What do you mean?

Comment: @npockmaka Your script is ok, I was thinking of an straight solution. Nothing to do with you, but with the OP question.

Comment: @npockmaka I apologize, I haven't read the last line of your post. _if don't want a whole new separate script you can just use the last for loop from the link_. Cannot delete post.

Answer (score 21):

I am totally late to this, but how about just using find to get rid of the unwanted lines:

```
 CertUtil -hashfile "path_to_file" MD5 | find /i /v "md5" | find /i /v "certutil"
```

Comment: How do I get this in a variable? Like I want the sha hash to be assigned to a variable like "hash", and then use the variable %hash% where I want to?

Answer (score 4):

Use powershell command:

```
$(CertUtil -hashfile C:\TEMP\MyDataFile.img MD5)[1] -replace " ",""
```

Answer (score 3):

you can with this ready to use [MD5.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/fileUtils/md5.bat):

```
call MD5.bat  "path_to_file" md5_var
echo %md5_var%
```

if don't want a whole new separate script you can just use the last for loop from the link.

Comment: Thanks for the link, this works for me:

`@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "md5="
for /f "skip=1 tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('certutil -hashfile "ping.txt" MD5') do (if not defined md5 (for %%Z in (%%#) do set "md5=!md5!%%Z"))
echo %md5%
endlocal`

Comment: I would vote as accepted answer if you extract the desired code along with the link... your bat file is cool, I just need the part without any checks. However, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Simple filter-out any lines contain other than alphanumeric characters

```
CertUtil -hashfile "path_to_file" MD5 | findstr /R "[0-9][a-z]"
```

Answer (score 0):

The MD5.bat works brilliantly.
I would just add the following to the top part.

set filesize=%~z1

if %filesize% lss 1 (

```
if "%~2" neq "" (
    endlocal && (
        set "%~2=0"
    ) 
) else (
    echo 0  
)
goto :eof
```

)

certUtil does not play nice with empty files, and returns an error.
Checking the filesize for empty files allow you to return a zero in this case, or any string you want when the file is empty instead.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following `checksum.bat` file:

```
@echo off
setlocal

REM Wrapper over built-in Windows utility `certutil` that removes spaces

set FILE_NAME=%~1
set CHECK_SUM=%~2

set RESULT=
for /f "delims=" %%s in ('certutil -hashfile "%FILE_NAME%" %CHECK_SUM% ^| find /i /v "%CHECK_SUM%" ^| find /i /v "certutil"') do (
    call :remove_spaces "%%s"
)

echo %RESULT%

exit /b

:remove_spaces
set SUM=%~1
set RESULT=%SUM: =%
exit /b
```

Usage example:

```
>checksum.bat some_file.zip SHA256
debea8cf24b93b6c34ec06bd4d85f4bc3b710d596419acbce25928e88e2805d0
```