# Remove empty lines and spaces from .txt-File with Batch

Tags: batch-file, sha1

I wanna use a batch-File to generate a SHA1-Key from user input(online-tools are not allowed) and show it on the console.
For hashing I use certutil. Following my code:

```
@ECHO OFF
TITLE MyBatchFile
ECHO Please enter the value
ECHO ===========================================
SET /p var=
ECHO %var%>temp_file.tmp
certutil -hashfile temp_file.tmp SHA1
PAUSE
DEL temp_file.tmp
EXIT
```

It works everything, except writing into the file temp_file.temp.
There I always have a carriage return and a space and I really don't get it how to remove those. For Hashing I need the exact string and no additional spaces and carriage returns.
I was looking for sevaral solutions in the web(e.g. following code) but I didn't found anyone that worked.

```
if exist "temp_file.tmp" findstr /R "^." "temp_file.tmp" >"file.tmp"
if exist "file.tmp" for %%I in ("file.tmp") do if %%~zI == 0 (del "file.tmp") else move /Y "file.tmp" "temp_file.tmp"
```

How can I write into the temp-File without any additional spaces, carriage returns, etc. or how can I remove these in the file?
Thank you for your answers

Phil

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38771114/saving-result-of-certutil-hashfile-to-a-variable-and-remove-spaces-of-the-hash/38772234#38772234

Comment: Tried that one out but also didn't work :(

Comment: replace your line `ECHO %var%>temp_file.tmp` with `echo|set /P ="%var%">temp_file.tmp`

Comment: @Gerhard: Thank you, your answer solved the problem.
I suppose the carriage return comes from the enter button when you finish the typing.