# How to get the hash of a string directly in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, hash, checksum

I just want to get the SHA256 checksum/hash of a string in my batch script using the Windows inbuilt certUtil utility.

I mean, I know that we can use certUtil for calculcating hashes of a file, but I just want it to calculate the hash of a string inside the batch script itself and store it as a variable like `%hash%`. The string will also be a variable basically like `%var%`.

Is there a simple way to do that?

**Alternative/complex Approach:**

I know a workaround in which we can write the variable into a file using:

```
echo %var% >>example.txt
```

And then calculating the hash of this file using:

```
CertUtil -hashfile "example.txt" SHA256
```

But this thing has its own set of problems:

- Firstly using `>>` also presses an `Enter` after writing `%var%` in the file, thereby changing the entire hash.
- Also I can't get the hash into the variable `%hash%` in this method. I tried everything in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38771114/saving-result-of-certutil-hashfile-to-a-variable-and-remove-spaces-of-the-hash), but can't get anything to work. (I'm a noob at batchfile programming)

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: `CertUtil -hashfile` does exactly that, it provides a hash for a file, it does not encode a string. I'd advise that you identify a utility, or scripting/programming mechanism, which provides the function you require of it instead.

Comment: Using file redirection does not create a CRLF at the end of your file. The `ECHO` command is doing that.

Comment: Incidentally, `>>` is not pressing `[ENTER]`, the enter, i.e. CRLF is part of the function of `ECHO`. There are many questions on this site which explain and show methods of printing without the CRLF. Please use the search facility to identify one, and adapt it as needed.

Comment: Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [ask] before you ask another ([similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70359480)) question!

Comment: Also, _(although possibly not relevant, once you've found out how to forego the CRLF)_, currently you are redirecting the expanded variable content followed by a single space character to the file, so have included an additional unwanted character too.

Comment: You can use something like `echo | set /p dummyValue="Some string or another">test.txt` to create a text file without a trailing space or CRLF.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the one-liner that you're looking for:

```
echo|set /p="foobar" > %TMP%/hash.txt |certutil -hashfile %TMP%/hash.txt SHA256 | findstr /v "hash"
```

The details of how to remove the `echo` new line can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105433/windows-batch-echo-without-new-line/7105690#7105690).